# Java RMI : how InitialContext.lookup() works

Tags: java, ejb, jndi, rmi

In a distributed client server application, i am using java RMI to invoke server side method from client machine. At server side EJB is being used and application server is Glassfish. I have a SampleFacade Class at server end which is a java session bean and SampleFacadeRemote is a Remote interface exposed to client (@Remote has been used with it). `SampleFacade` implements `SampleFacadeRemote` Interface .

Please look at the following code snippet :

```
        private static SampleFacadeRemote lookupSampleFacade()
        {
            Context c = new InitialContext();
            return (SampleFacadeRemote)c.lookup("java:comp/env/SampleFacade");
        }
        catch (NamingException ne)
       {
          throw new RuntimeException(ne);
       }
```

Here, with the returned object, remote method can be successfully executed.

I am curious to know how it works. Does lookup method return `SampleFacade` object to client in order to execute its method? But `SampleFacade`'s method is suppose to be run at server side/Remote JVM. then what type of object is being returned by `lookup()` method? Please explain the underlying mechanism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It returns a stub: a client-side object that implements the same remote interface and knows how to communicate with the actual remote object.

In fact you should note that it isn't the `lookup()` method that performs this magic: it is ultimately the remote object itself that translates itself to its stub. The stub is already in the Registry or LDAP or whatever you're looking up, and `lookup()` just gives you whatever was found.